# Neo4j BatchInserter using setNodeProperties to set an array with values

Tags: neo4j

I am using the **BatchInserter** instance to get and set properties for nodes.
My data have multiple values in some properties.

```
property value
======== =========
synonym  animal
synonym  mammalian
```

I want to put this values, in the same property in the same node.

I have used the following code snippet to read and set values:

```
String[] values = {"animal", "mammalian"};
for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {
    Map<String, Object> nodeProps = db.getNodeProperties(0); // Node 0 properties
    nodeProps.put("synonym", values[i]);
    db.setNodeProperties(0, nodeProps);
}
```

In the first iteration property `synonym` gets value `animal`. In the second iteration, the property is *overridden* by the value `mammalian`.

My question is: How can I get the previous value(s), add the new one and set the property to the node so I can get `synonym=['animal', 'mammalian']` in graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have multiple values on a node/relationship property you need to use arrays. So you have on property `synonyms` with a `String[]` as value:

To amend an existing property:

```
String[] values = {"animal", "mammalian"};
Map<String, Object> nodeProps = db.getNodeProperties(0); 
String[] existingValues = nodeProps.get("synonym");
// using org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils from Apache Commons Lang:
String[] amendedValues = ArrayUtils.addAll(existingValues, values); 
nodeProps.put("synonym", amendedValues);
db.setNodeProperties(0, nodeProps);
```